# Perform SQLDump on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to perform a SQL Dump in a SQL Server? Because on mysql we can easily do that with `mysqldump` command but on a SQL Server when I try to export the data it seems that it's only allowing to export per table and not per database. Now when I try to do the copy database it tries to copy the source db to a destination db. Now I came from MYSQL and I thought that it will somehow behave the same way.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks for those who will reply

Comment: well are you just trying to export the whole db to another location? whats the end result desired?

Comment: @DougCoats I was thinking of exporting it into a flat file or something? then import it into my local. The Source DB is in AWS so I want to have a copy on my local. I have only RDP access to the Window Server and I don't have the actual password. So my only option is to export the flat file or something. What should be the best approach?

Comment: You could technically do what you want by using the generate scripts command, then going into the advanced properties on the last page, and selecting "data and schema".  But that's a horrible idea for anything other than the most trivial of databases, and the script it generates will probably not work anyway, due to getting dependencies in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server you would either use [Backup and Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-and-restore-of-sql-server-databases?view=sql-server-2017), or extract all the schema and data into a [.bacpac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/data-tier-applications?view=sql-server-2017) file.

Comment: Thanks for this will try restoring it. I think this is what I'm looking for